# Multiplication with Fixed point representation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, multiplication, hdl, fixed-point

For the fixed point arithmatic I represented 0.166 with 0000 0010101010100110 and multiply it with same. for this I wrote the code in VHDL as below. Output is assigned in y which is signed 41bit. For signed Multiplication A(a1,b1)*A(a2,b2)=A(a1+a2+1,b1+b2).  However during the simulation its give an error

```
      Target Size 41 and source size 40 for array dimension 0 does not match.
```

code:

```
 entity file1 is
    Port ( y : out signed(40 downto 0));
 end file1;

 architecture Behavioral of file1 is

 signal a : signed(19 downto 0) := "00000010101010100110";
 signal b : signed(19 downto 0) := "00000010101010100110";

 begin
    y<= (a*b);    ----error
 end Behavioral;
```

Comment: dk14's answer details why the lengths are what they are, which is worthwhile, but it might be easier just to remember that, in general, the result length for multiplication is just the sum of the operand lengths, for both `signed` and `unsigned`. 20-bit * 20-bit = 40-bit.

Comment: If you really want fixed point, why not use sfixed from the IEEE fixed point package (VHDL-2008 addition)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of multiplying 19+1 bits to 19+1 bits is 39+1 bits, while your port is 40+1 bit long. For example let's multiply maximum possible values for 19-bits: `0x7FFFF * 0x7FFFF = 0x3FFFF00001` - so it's 39 bits (19 + 19 + carry) for unsigned result and +1 bit for sign.

So you should either "normalize" result by extending it to 1 more bit, which should be equal to the sign of result (bit#40 = bit#39) or just choose 40-bit port as output:

```
Port ( y : out signed(39 downto 0))
```

If you really need redundant 41st bit:

```
begin
   y(39 downto 0) <= (a*b)
   y(40) <= y(39)
end Behavioral;
```

Or just use `resize` function for signeds: [How to convert 8 bits to 16 bits in VHDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451492/how-to-convert-8-bits-to-16-bits-in-vhdl)

Comment: For normalizing , should we extend the bit in a,b?  How to check the resultant bit for any other range.  I read in that i got result should be a1+a2+1  as i wrote in question.

Comment: No. if you extend a,b you will receive 42-bits result, when you need 41. As VHDL uses Two's Complement representation of number - it's enough to just duplicate the sign(bit#39) in new bit (bit#40) of result.

Comment: a1+a2+1 = 19+19+1 **for unsigned!**; and + 1 for sign :). So "+1" for carry and "+1" more for sign. See the example with maximum possible values in my answer.