# VHDL: Assigning a smaller std_logic_vector to a bigger one

Tags: range, vhdl, assign, human-readable

I'm trying to assign a smaller `std_logic_vector` to a bigger one like this:

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity subarray_tb is
end subarray_tb;


architecture VERHALTEN of subarray_tb is 

signal big : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := x"A5A5";
signal small : std_Logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"F0";

begin

  big <= small;

end VERHALTEN;
```

As expected I get the following error from within Modelsim:

> ** Error (suppressible): C:/altera/15.1/subarray_tb.vhd(19): (vcom-1272) Length of expected is 16; length of actual is 8.

I know how to fix this, but I'm not happy with the result, cause it looks very unreadable:

```
big(big'LEFT downto (big'LEFT-small'LENGTH+1)) <= small;
```

I don't want to use fixed ranges in the brackets cause my real problem is a bit more complex. The smaller array is a concatenation of different std_logic_vectors, so I want the solution to be flexible.

Has anyone a nicer solution that is more human readable?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451492/how-to-convert-8-bits-to-16-bits-in-vhdl

Comment: Wrap the unreadable in an appropriately named function. This is not quite a duplicate as the questioner apparently wants a partial update, leaving the low bits of `big` unchanged (or undefined).

Comment: You could declare an alias of `big`. E.g. `alias big_upper : std_logic_vector is big(15 downto 8);`

Comment: @scary_jeff I have a simple test for determining whether another question is a duplicate: do the alleged duplicate question's answers answer the original question? They don't in this case.

Comment: @Paebbels This is exactly how I'd recommend attacking this.  Excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could used a *named range*. You define a `subtype`:

```
subtype big_upper is integer range big'LEFT downto (big'LEFT-small'LENGTH+1);
```

And then use it instead of a range:

```
big(big_upper) <= small;
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Pcn